# Bash one liner to open herrie (command line music player) in new terminal and playing a song

Tags: bash, macos

I'm new to bash and I wanted to created a one line command that opens an new terminal and executes a command to open herrie and play a song.

```
#!/bin/bash

open -n -F -a iTerm.app --args herrie -p Feeling\ Good.mp3/
```

The open commands works, the second command to open herrie works, however it doesn't play a song and when I close the terminal I get a broken pipe error.

Comment: How about just `x-terminal-emulator herrie -p Feeling\ Good.mp3/`?

Comment: @Maverbot my terminal does not recongines x-terminal-emulator command

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using MacOS Mojave with ohmyzsh iTerm2 extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use osascript:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "herrie -p YOUR_SONG.mp3"
end tell'
```

Comment: This script fixes the broken pipe, however it still doesn't play the song

Comment: well it should work correctly. the only reason I could think of is space in filenames. for your example try using two backslashes.

Feeling\\ Good.mp3

Comment: also before putting it in a file, try the code in terminal emulator. this way you can actually see the errors.

Comment: I removed the spaces from the file and now it your script works. thank you for the help